# i have implemented custom dialog with paint view ...how to get the paint view on image view from dialog

Tags: java, android

i have created one small app in which on main activity there is one image view and one button. on button click dialog is opening and user can draw any thing on canvas.now i want to set this canvas to be set on my main screen image view how to do this?..pls see the images

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking please be clear what you are trying to do

Comment: on my main screen ther is one button which open dialog.......in dialog i have implement drawable view ...now i want to set this drawable view to on my main screen ....after click ok

Comment: you want to display a dialog with your custom view in drawable folder am I right??

Comment: that i have already done......now i want to set that custome view to set as image on my main screen image view

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in your activity

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourcustomview, null);//add your view from drawable folder
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText);//view from custom dialog
editText.setText("test");
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

**Edit:** set your imageview drawsble in xml code with `android:background="@drawable/your_custom_dialog"`

Comment: edited my question with image...pls see if u know how to do that ...dialog is done ...but dont know what to do on add button

Comment: what to do on add button?